# Almacenar ruta de un archivo PDF en MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Me gustaría saber cómo puedo almacenar la ruta de un archivo PDF que subo a través de un formulario.

El `index.php` es:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action="guardar.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                </div>
<div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Nombre</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nombre" placeholder="Nombre">
                </div>
            </div>
<div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Acta de nacimiento</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <input type="file" class="form-control" name="archivo1">
                </div>
            </div>
<div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Guardar</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
```

El archivo `guardar.php` es:

```
<?php

require 'conexion.php';

$nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
$sql = "INSERT INTO personas (nombre) VALUES ('$nombre')";
$resultado = $mysqli->query($sql);
$id_insert = $mysqli->insert_id;

if($_FILES["archivo1"]["error"]>0){
    echo "Error al cargar archivo"; 
    } else {

    $permitidos = array("image/gif","image/png","application/pdf");
    $limite_kb = 800;

    if(in_array($_FILES["archivo1"]["type"], $permitidos) && $_FILES["archivo1"]["size"] <= $limite_kb * 1024){

        $ruta = 'files/acta'.$id_insert.'/';
        $archivo = $ruta.$_FILES["archivo1"]["name"];


        if(!file_exists($ruta)){
            mkdir($ruta);           }

        if(!file_exists($archivo)){

            $resultado = @move_uploaded_file($_FILES["archivo1"]["tmp_name"], $archivo);

            if($resultado){
                echo "";
                } else {
                echo "Error al guardar archivo";
            }

            } else {
            echo "Archivo ya existe";
        }

        } else {
        echo "Archivo no permitido o excede el tamaño";
    }

}
```

Tengo que añadir que se guarda tanto el registro del nombre en la base de datos como el archivo PDF en el directorio `files/actaN`, donde `N` es el número que se obtiene al insertar el registro.

Pero quisiera saber cómo puedo insertar la ruta donde se encuentra el archivo en la base de datos, por decir, entrar en phpmyadmin y al ver la tabla `personas` en la columna de `acta` se vea `files/acta1/nombre.pdf`.

Comment: ¿Esa ruta que quieres no es la de tu variable $archivo ?

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a la comunidad. Te invito a hacer el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y leer [¿cómo preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea bien recibida por parte de la comunidad. Además, para poder reproducir tu problema y encontrar una solución fácilmente nos sería de gran ayuda un [ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: En particular, en esta pregunta: ¿podrías decir en qué tabla piensas guardar esa información y cuáles son los campos? Puedes compartir el esquema usando `SHOW CREATE TABLE <tabla>`. Sin esa información no te podemos decir la mejor forma de insertar el registro o actualizar el existente.

Comment: La tabla donde lo guardo se llama "personas" y solo tiene esos dos campos por el momento, donde se guarda el nombre y donde se supone que guardaría la ruta, ambas columnas son "nombre" y "acta", no tiene nada más @OscarGarcia

Comment: Sí, esa ruta es la que quisiera aparezca en la base de datos, que tiene solo una tabla con dos columnas, una para nombre y la otra para el documento pdf con el nombre de acta... @JavierTarrazona

Comment: Ángeles, imagino que también tendrá un campo autoincrementable, ¿cómo se llama ese campo autoincrementable?

Comment: @OscarGarcia id, en total solo 3 campos, id, nombre y acta.

Comment: En unas tres horas te redactaré una respuesta con la forma correcta de hacerlo (ahora no estoy delante del PC).

Comment: @OscarGarcia está bien, comprendo, muchas gracias de antemano

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La primera forma de solucionar tu problema es haciendo una actualización del registro previamente insertado conteniendo el valor de la ruta del archivo:

```
UPDATE personas
SET acta = 'nombre del archivo'
WHERE id = 'id obtenido en el INSERT'
```

Es muy importante que uses [`mysqli::real_escape_string()`](https://php.net/es/mysqli.real-escape-string) para evitar los [graves problemas de seguridad](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EpKIhF7naSY) asociados a la [inyección SQL](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inyecci%C3%B3n_SQL).

Un ejemplo de cómo hacer esta actualización:

```
<?php
require 'conexion.php';

/* Procura no usar variables intermedias, usa siempre las originales */
$sql = "
  INSERT INTO personas (
    nombre
  ) VALUES (
    '". mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['nombre']) ."'
  )
";
$resultado = $mysqli->query($sql);
if ($resultado === false) {
  die(htmlspecialchars('Error en inserción: '. $mysqli->error));
}
$id_insert = $mysqli->insert_id;

if ($_FILES["archivo1"]["error"] > 0) {
  echo "Error al cargar archivo"; 
} else {
  $permitidos = array(
    "image/gif",
    "image/png",
    "application/pdf"
  );
  $limite_kb = 800;

  /* La comprobación de tamaño es innecesaria(*) */
  if (in_array($_FILES["archivo1"]["type"], $permitidos)
    && $_FILES["archivo1"]["size"] <= $limite_kb * 1024
  ) {
    $ruta = 'files/acta'. $id_insert .'/';
    $archivo = $ruta . $_FILES["archivo1"]["name"];
    if (!file_exists($ruta)) {
      mkdir($ruta);
    }
    if (!file_exists($archivo)) {
      $resultado = @move_uploaded_file(
        $_FILES["archivo1"]["tmp_name"],
        $archivo
      );
      /* Si se copió correctamente actualizaremos en la base de datos la ruta */
      if ($resultado !== false) {
        $sql = "
          UPDATE personas
          SET acta = '". mysqli->real_escape_string($archivo) ."'
          WHERE id = '". mysqli->real_escape_string($id_insert) ."'
        ";
        $resultado = $mysqli->query($sql);
        if ($resultado === false) {
          die(htmlspecialchars('Error en actualización: '. $mysqli->error));
        }
      } else {
        echo "Error al guardar archivo";
      }
    } else {
      echo "Archivo ya existe";
    }
  } else {
    echo "Archivo no permitido o excede el tamaño";
  }
}
```

Aunque el contenido de `$id_insert` es un número entero, fíjate que también puede insertarse como cadena entrecomillada sin ningún problema.

---

La segunda manera de realizar el trabajo es realizando una única inserción con el nombre del archivo ya elegido.

Aunque podríamos conocer el siguiente valor del campo `id` a través de la siguiente consulta:

```
SELECT
  AUTO_INCREMENT id
FROM
  information_schema.tables
WHERE
  table_name = 'personas'
  AND table_schema = DATABASE()
```

Es mejor generar de antemano el nombre del archivo a partir del [picadillo SHA-1 del archivo (`sha1_file()`)](https://php.net/es/function.sha1-file).

Además, este sistema dificulta que descarguen los archivos que alojes en tu servidor "intuyendo" la secuencia numérica de los directorios y su contenido.

Ejemplo:

```
<?php
require 'conexion.php';

/* Bandera para indicar la copia del archivo correcta */
$guardado = false;
if ($_FILES["archivo1"]["error"] > 0) {
  echo "Error al cargar archivo"; 
} else {
  $permitidos = array(
    "image/gif",
    "image/png",
    "application/pdf"
  );
  $limite_kb = 800;

  /* La comprobación de tamaño es innecesaria(*) */
  if (in_array($_FILES["archivo1"]["type"], $permitidos)
    && $_FILES["archivo1"]["size"] <= $limite_kb * 1024
  ) {
    $ruta = 'files/';
    /* A "acta." le agregamos el picadillo SHA-1 del archivo */
    $archivo = $ruta .'acta.'. sha1_file($_FILES["archivo1"]["tmp_name"]);
    /* Y por último le agregamos el nombre del archivo original al final */
    $archivo .= '.'. $_FILES["archivo1"]["name"];
    if (!file_exists($ruta)) {
      mkdir($ruta);
    }
    if (!file_exists($archivo)) {
      $resultado = @move_uploaded_file(
        $_FILES["archivo1"]["tmp_name"],
        $archivo
      );
      /* Si se copió correctamente lo indicaremos con esta bandera */
      if ($resultado !== false) {
        $guardado = true;
      } else {
        echo "Error al guardar archivo";
      }
    } else {
      echo "Archivo ya existe";
    }
  } else {
    echo "Archivo no permitido o excede el tamaño";
  }
}
if ($guardado === true) {
  /* Si se realizó la copia correctamente, guardaremos la información del archivo */
  $sql = "
    INSERT INTO personas (
      nombre,
      acta
    ) VALUES (
      '". mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['nombre']) ."',
      '". mysqli->real_escape_string($archivo) ."'
    )
  ";
} else {
  /* En caso contrario únicamente guardaremos el nombre (¿sería útil?) */
  $sql = "
    INSERT INTO personas (
      nombre
    ) VALUES (
      '". mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['nombre']) ."'
    )
  ";
}
$resultado = $mysqli->query($sql);
if ($resultado === false) {
  die(htmlspecialchars('Error en inserción: '. $mysqli->error));
}
/* En este caso no nos interesa para nada el identificador obtenido */
```

Comment: Wow, realmente funcionó de esa manera, es decir, seguí investigando un poco y pues he complementado con lo que me has comentado así que, muchísimas gracias por tomarte el tiempo para explicarme. @OscarGarcia

Comment: Un placer ser de ayuda :)

Answer (score 2):

Igual lo más sencillo es que crees una tabla nueva o un fichero .ini de parámetros donde guardes los datos de la ruta donde dejas los PDFs, es decir, en la tabla sólo guardas el nombre del fichero y, bien en la tabla de configuración o en el fichero .ini defines un campo/variable donde guardas la ruta.
Así, si por el motivo que sea cambias la rutas de los ficheros PDF tan sólo tienes que poner la ruta en la tabla/variable correspondiente a la ruta.

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a la comunidad. Te invito a hacer el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y leer [¿cómo escribo una buena respuesta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) para que tu respuesta sea bien recibida por parte de la comunidad. En particular, si esto no soluciona la pregunta planteada por el OP, quizá deberías ponerlo como comentario y no como respuesta.